# Screen scrollable issue when click on text filed keyboard covers the content(text filed)

Tags: flutter

Using Screenutilinit function by importing flutter screenutil package for responsiveness but then due to this I'm facing issue as the screens are not scrollable and the keyboard covers the content even after using SingleChildScroll view, also I have tried with changing resizetoAvoidBottomInset to true and maintaining the bottom padding

```
//Converted from stateful to stateless
class Connect extends StatelessWidget {
  final isLoggedin;
  Connect({super.key, required this.isLoggedin});

  final credentials = CredentialManager.getSavedCredentials();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      builder: (context, child) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(context),
        child: GetMaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'BizConnect App',
          theme: MyAppTheme.getThemeData(context),
          initialBinding: HomeScreenBinding(),
          // getPages: AppPages.routes,
          // initialRoute: isLoggedin ? AppRoutes.HOME_SCREEN: AppRoutes.START,

          // if islogged true show Homescreen else IntroductionScreens
          home: isLoggedin ? SignUpWithGmail() : IntroductionPage(),

          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? widget) {
            final MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
            return MediaQuery(
              data: mediaQueryData.copyWith(
                platformBrightness: Brightness.light,
                alwaysUse24HourFormat: true,
                boldText: false,
              ),
              child: ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
                BouncingScrollWrapper.builder(context, widget!),
                maxWidth: 1284,
                minWidth: 393,
                // 393 × 1284
                // maxWidth: 3072,
                // minWidth: 1920,

                // maxWidth: 852,
                // minWidth: 393,
                defaultScale: true,
                breakpoints: const <ResponsiveBreakpoint>[
                  ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(393, name: MOBILE),
                  ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: MOBILE),
                  ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
                  ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1000, name: TABLET),
                  ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(1200, name: DESKTOP),
                  ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(2460, name: "4K"),
                ],
                background: Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(bottom: mediaQueryData.viewInsets.bottom),
                  child: Container(
                    color: const Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                    height: mediaQueryData.size.height,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      designSize: const Size(393, 852),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class SignUpWithGmail extends StatelessWidget {
  final gmailVerificationController = Get.put(SignUpWithGmailController());

  SignUpWithGmail({super.key});
  final sizedBox = SizedBox(
    height: 30.h,
  );

  final textFieldPadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 39.w);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
        // Scaffold(
        /* appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Gmail Verification',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 17.sp),
        ),
        leadingWidth: 80,
        leading: TextButton(
            onPressed: () 
            {
              Get.back();
              Get.delete<GmailverificationControler>();
              gmailVerificationController.makeFieldEmpty();
            },
            child: Text(
              'Back',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 17.sp),
            )),
        // actions: [
        //   TextButton(
        //       onPressed: () {},
        //       child: Text(
        //         'Done',
        //         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 17.sp),
        //       )),
        // ],
      ), */
        // body:

        SingleChildScrollView(
      /*
         NEW UPADTE MAKES IT REMOVABLE 
                
       
         child: Padding(
          padding: textFieldPadding,
 */

      child: Form(
        // autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode,
        key: gmailVerificationController.signUpGmailFormKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            /*

                NEW UPADTE MAKES IT REMOVABLE 
                
                
                
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 115,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Create Profile',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 1.w,
                      fontSize: 30.sp),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 77.5,
                ), */

           Obx(() =>  CustomTextFormField(
              enabled:
                  gmailVerificationController.isGamilVerified.value == false
                      ? true
                      : false,
              focusNode: gmailVerificationController.userNameFocus,
              hintText: 'Enter your User Name',
              labelText: 'User Name',
              suffix: const Icon(
                Icons.person_outlined,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 138, 148, 166),
              ),
              controller:
                  gmailVerificationController.userNameTEController.value,
              // onchanged: gmailVerificationController.user,\
              onchanged: (value) {},
              textInputType: TextInputType.name,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              // suffixConstraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 48.h),
              validator: FormValidation.validateUsername,

              // autofocus: true,
            ),),
            sizedBox,
           Obx(() =>  CustomTextFormField(
              enabled:
                  gmailVerificationController.isGamilVerified.value == false
                      ? true
                      : false,
              focusNode: gmailVerificationController.firstNameFocus,
              hintText: 'Enter your First Name',
              labelText: 'First Name',
              suffix: const Icon(
                Icons.person_outlined,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 138, 148, 166),
              ),
              controller:
                  gmailVerificationController.firstNameTEController.value,

              textInputType: TextInputType.name,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              // suffixConstraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 48.h),
              validator: FormValidation.validateFirstName,
              autofocus: true,
            ),),
            sizedBox,
            Obx(() => CustomTextFormField(
              enabled:
                  gmailVerificationController.isGamilVerified.value == false
                      ? true
                      : false,
              focusNode: gmailVerificationController.lastNameFocus,
              hintText: 'Enter your Last Name',
              labelText: 'Last Name',
              suffix: const Icon(
                Icons.person_outlined,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 138, 148, 166),
              ),
              controller:
                  gmailVerificationController.lastNameTEController.value,

              textInputType: TextInputType.name,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              // suffixConstraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 48.h),
              validator: FormValidation.validateLastName,
              autofocus: true,
            ),),
            sizedBox,
           Obx(() =>  CustomTextFormField(
              enabled:
                  gmailVerificationController.isGamilVerified.value == false
                      ? true
                      : false,
              focusNode: gmailVerificationController.mobileNumberFocus,
              hintText: 'Enter your Mobile Number',
              labelText: 'Mobile No.',
              suffix: const Icon(
                Icons.call,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 138, 148, 166),
              ),
              controller:
                  gmailVerificationController.mobileNumberTEController.value,

              textInputType: TextInputType.phone,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              // suffixConstraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 48.h),
              validator: FormValidation.validateMobileNo,
            ),),
            sizedBox,
           Obx(() =>  CustomTextFormField(
              enabled:
                  gmailVerificationController.isGamilVerified.value == false
                      ? true
                      : false,
              focusNode: gmailVerificationController.gmailFocus,
              hintText: 'Enter Your e-mail',
              labelText: 'Recovery e-mail',
              suffix: const Icon(
                Icons.email_outlined,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 138, 148, 166),
              ),
              controller:
                  gmailVerificationController.recoveryEmailTEController.value,
              onchanged: (value) {
                gmailVerificationController.isGamilVerified.value == false;
              },
              onEditingComplete: () async {
                gmailVerificationController.gmailFocus.unfocus();
                if (gmailVerificationController.signUpGmailFormKey.currentState!
                    .validate()) {
                  await gmailVerificationController.checkEmailAndUserExist();
                }
              },
              textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              validator: FormValidation.validateEmail,
            ),),
```

In the above mentioned page i'm encountering the issue, where im using form with list(Column) of text fileds, when tap on a very end of the text field keyboard covers the text filed instead of screen scroll up.